# csvjoin error: "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, LazyFile found"

Tags: python, csv, csvkit

I'm trying to join two files using the `csvjoin` command from `csvkit`. One csv is much larger than the other, but they both have a column in common, an RD code (with a column name of "RD"). Assuming that it's not a problem for `csvjoin` to match on just the rows that have the same RD codes, I'm not sure why this command isn't working: `csvjoin RD all-crimes-2012.csv some-crimes-2012.csv > joined-2012.csv`

I'm getting this error: "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, LazyFile found". I thought maybe the encoding was wrong so I saved each csv with UTF-8 encoding and tried the command again -- got the same error. There are a couple other people who've asked the same question in regards to the `csvjoin` command, but I haven't seen any answer.

I'm on Python 2.7.15 on Sierra.

Any ideas on what the problem might be? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your command seems wrong. If you specify column name, you must use `-c`, than `csvjoin -c RD all-crimes-2012.csv some-crimes-2012.csv > joined-2012.csv`